# Proving divisibility of sum of seven consecutive integers by 7 using congruence theories

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I have have this peculiar problem below;

For which values of n, a consecutive set of seven integers, raised to it's `nth` power and added together, will be divisible by 7?

For example if a is any integer then the sum of seven consecutive integers when n=1 is;

a + (a+1) + (a+2) + (a+3) +  (a+4) + (a+5) + (a+6) = **7a+21**

which is divisible by 7.

I can prove it's divisible using polynomials for **n=2,3 or 4** but that doesn't involve the use of congruence theories. I tried to apply Fermat Little Theorem, but it didn't get me anywhere

Comment: It's not divisible if $n$ is a multiple of $6$, because then all the powers are $1\pmod7$ except for that of the multiple of $7$, which is $0$, so the sum is $6\pmod7$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4,a+5$, and $a+6$ comprise a complete set of residues modulo $7$,

so we can take $a=0$ without loss of generality.

For $n=1$, the sum is congruent to $0+1+2+3+4+5+6\equiv0\bmod7$.

For $n=2$, the sum is congruent to $0+1+4+2+2+4+1\equiv0\bmod7$.

For $n=3$, the sum is congruent to $0+1+1-1+1-1-1\equiv0\bmod7$.

For $n=4$, the sum is congruent to $0+1+2+4+4+2+1\equiv0\bmod7$.

For $n=5$, the sum is congruent to $0+1+4+5+2+3+6\equiv0\bmod7$.

For $n=6$, the sum is congruent to $0+1+1+1+1+1+1\equiv6\bmod7$.

For $n=6k+m$, the sum is congruent to that for $m$, as a consequence of Fermat's little theorem.

Therefore, the sum is a multiple of $7$ unless $n$ is a multiple of $6$.

Comment: This is very good, Thanks! 
For n=0, it holds true for any 7 consecutive integers as long as 0 is not there.

Comment: @wawass:  I took out $n=0$ and put in $n=6$ to avoid that can of worms

Answer (score 2):

You are asking (in the case $p=7$), for which $n$: $$S_n=\sum_{a\in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}} a^n\equiv 0 \mod p.$$

I once set this as a coursework question because I wanted the students to appreciate that multiplication by a non-zero element modulo a prime is a permutation.

That is $x^nS_n\equiv S_n \mod p$ for all $x\not\equiv 0 \mod p$.  Thus there are two possibilities:

1. $S_n \equiv 0 \mod p$ so $p|S_n$,

or

2. $x^n\equiv 1 \mod p$ for all  $x\not\equiv 0 \mod p$.  Thus $S_n\equiv p-1 \mod p$ so $p|S_n+1$.

As the non-zero residues modulo $p$ are a cyclic group of order $p-1$, the second case occurs precisely when $p-1|n$.

So you may conclude that when $p=7$, you have $7|S_n$ if and only if $6\not\!|n$.  If $6|n$ then $7|S_n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Your result is true if $n$ is odd.**

Indeed, take $7$ consecutive numbers $a_1$,..., $a_7$.

If $n$ is odd, you have modulo $7$
$$a_1^n + ... + a_7^n = 1^n + 2^n + 3^n + 4^n + 5^n + 6^n + 7^n = 1^n + 2^n + 3^n + (-3)^n + (-2)^n + (-1)^n = 0$$

so $a_1^n + ... + a_7^n$ is divisible by $7$.

Comment: but those are then only time it is true.  For example if $n = 2$ then $\sum a_i^2 \equiv 1^2 + 2^2 +3^2 + 4^2 +5^2 + 6^2 + 7^2 \equiv 1 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 4 + 1 + 0 \equiv 14\equiv 0 \pmod 7$.

Comment: @fleablood I don't understand what you mean, but I know that there are possibilities for even $n$ (some answers already state that). I just wanted to provide a very simple proof in the case where $n$ is odd. I never said that the result is not true if $n$ is not odd.

Comment: But that question was for which $n$ is it true.  To answer it is true for odd $n$ is not a complete answer.

Comment: Where did I say that it is a complete answer ?

Comment: "Where did I say that it is a complete answer ?" Well, no-where I guess, but then again you never said this wasn't a Buffy the Vampire Slayer erotic fan fiction either.  I just assumed that as this is posted as an answer to the OPs question, that it is actually meant to be an answer to the OPs question.  If it's  " a very simple proof in the case where n is odd" or a Buffy the Vampire Slayer erotic fan fiction and not actually an answer I think that should have been made clear.

Comment: I think this is clear. Notice that nobody commented to say "This is not a Buffy the Vampire Slayer erotic fan fiction".

Answer (score -2):

First of all if $a_1, a_2,....,a_7$ are consecutive then then are congruent to a complete residue class.  That is for $r_1, .....r_2 = 0,....,6$ then exactly one $a_i$ is congrent to each $r_i$.

By Fermat's little thereom if $n = 6k + j$ then $a_i^n\equiv (a_i^{6})^ka_i^j \equiv \begin{cases}0\equiv a_i^j\pmod 7 &a_i\equiv 0 \pmod 7\\1^ka_i^j\equiv a_i^j\pmod 7&a_i\not \equiv 0\pmod 7\end{cases}\equiv a_i^j$

So we need do test these for $n\equiv j; j=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Now $6\equiv -1$ and $5\equiv -2$ and $4 \equiv -3\pmod 7$ so

$a_1^n + a_2^n + ... + a_7^n \equiv ((-3)^j + (3)^j) + ((-2)^j + 2^j) + (-1^j + 1^j) + 0^j\pmod 7$.

If $j$ is odd we are done $(-m)^j + m^j\equiv 0 \pmod 7$ and the sum is equivalent to $0\pmod 7$.

If $j$ is even we'll have to try them.

If $j = 0$ we have $a_1^n + a_2^n + ... + a_7^n \equiv 1+1+1+1+1+1+0\equiv 6\pmod 7$.  No good.

If $j=2$ we have $a_1^n + a_2^n + ... + a_7^n\equiv 9+9+4+4+1+1+0\equiv 2*14\equiv 0$.  So that is good.

If $j=4$ we have $a_1^n + a_2^n + ... + a_7^n\equiv 2*3^4 + 2*2^4+2*1^4+0\equiv 2*9^2 +2*16 + 2\equiv 2*2^2 + 2*2 + 2= 8+ 6=1-1\equiv 0\pmod 7$.  So that is good.

So the only time this does not work is if $n$ is a multiple of $6$.

=====

I could probably have done this a little slicker to note that $3$ is a primitive root mod $7$. ($3^{k=1,2,....,6}\equiv 3,2,6,4,5,1\pmod 7$) and so $\sum a_i^n\equiv \sum_{i\ne 0} 3^{in}$ but then noteting that $3^k\equiv - 3^{k+3\pmod 6}$ the terms cancel out so long as $n\not \equiv 0\pmod 6$.  (And for $n\equiv 0 \pmod 6$ it is evident that $\sum a_i^n\equiv \sum_{a_i\not \equiv 0\pmod 7} 1\equiv -1\pmod 7$.)